# How to original log line numbers with AspectJ and log4j?

Tags: java, spring, log4j, aop

How can I log original line numbers of my method with AspectJ(Spring) framework? I'm new to aop programming, so I just want to know if it's possible or how to? Since aop will delegate the invocation process of my method, which generates new class and new method, line numbers logged are always not original ones.

Below are some of my codes:

Schema-based aop configuration:

```
<bean id="logInterceptor" class="com.fuhu.appsub.aop.LogInterceptor"></bean>
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="logDBAspect" ref="logInterceptor">
    <aop:pointcut id="logDBPointcut" expression="execution(*            com.fuhu.appsub.service..*(..)) " />
        <aop:after-throwing  pointcut-ref="logDBPointcut" throwing="ex" method="logDBException"/>           
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Here's my delegated method:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=true)
public List<Item> findByName (String name) throws Exception{
    try
    {
        List<Item> itemList = itemRepository.findByName(name);
        int i=0,j=1;
        int k = j/i;
        return itemList;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.getMessage() + "in findByName with name=" + name + "  file:" + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getFileName() + "  line:" + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber());
    }
}
```

Here's my delegating method:

```
 public void logDBException( JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception ex) {
         if(loggerDB.isErrorEnabled()){
             loggerDB.error(ex.getMessage());
         }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [full AspectJ or just Spring's AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-spring-or-aspectj)? Spring AOP [is primarily based](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-proxies) on Java [dynamic proxies](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html). It's usually enough to do what you need, it's fairly straightforward, and it doesn't really interfere with stack trace line numbers at all.

Comment: Obviously I read your question before it was complete. You're using Spring AOP, and therefore you should be getting accurate line numbers out of it; however, I've never used Thread.getStackTrace, so perhaps you're getting some peculiar behavior out of that.

As a point of style, catching Exception is very poor practice, as is throwing Exception. It's also worth noting that a thrown exception has its own stacktrace, from which your logDBException method could easily extract the information needed rather than building it into the exception message.

Comment: Hey Ryan, I got it working with what you said, really thanks a lot to you.

Answer (score 1):

Even real AspectJ does not change the line number of your original code.

That is because the line number in class files is stored in the line number table. And this table allows it to have multiple statements in one "line". So even the extra AOP invocations must not change the line number.

Comment: If you are using something like Sonar, code style won't allow you to put multiple statements on one line.